# Can an app written with .net Compact Framework restart itself?

Tags: compact-framework, self-updating

Can an app written with .net Compact Framework restart itself?

What are some of the common patterns to achieve this? I would like to have a self-updating application that restarts itself if update was done.

Of course, I could have 2 .exe: one that updates and the actual app, but I would rather just have one.

Comment: If you can have two instances of the app running at the same time, just have the app launch itself and then exit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Absolutely.  It's actually way easier to do than on the desktop.  If you're using the SDF, use this:

```
var thisName = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase;
var time = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(11);
Notify.RunAppAtTime(thisName, time);
```

If you want to do it manually, you'd [p/invoke CeRunAppAtTime](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/coredll/CeRunAppAtTime.html).

Note that you *must* have a launch time of > 10 (not >= 10) seconds in the future or the "launch will happen immediately (an artifact of how the default notification setup is set in the kernel).

Comment: Should this necessarily be placed inside Program.cs file? I am placing this inside the Form code behind and nothing happens. Also, can I pass arguments to my app using this code? If possible, how? Thank you!

Comment: It should work from anywhere, but in any case you must shut the currently running app down after you make the call.

Comment: And no, you can't pass any arguments to the other app instance.

Comment: thank you! I just verified it and that seemed to be the case - the current app was still running. once closed, it restarted.

Comment: @ctacke So this will restart the application after 11 secs the current application shut down-right.Application.Exit() should comes after the restart code or before the restart code.Please clarify.

Comment: Yes, you would exit the app right after calling this and your app will re-start in 11 seconds.

Comment: @ctacke I am using this in compact framework 3.5. and I tried in emulator but application is not getting restarted.I am not getting any exception also.Did restart functionality work in emulator,Thanks.